# LambdaJ class property matcher

Tags: java, hamcrest, lambdaj

I am trying to write a Hamcrest matcher to verify the return value of a method that returns a Class object. For example, given the class:

```
public static class ClassHolder {
    private final Class clazz;

    public ClassHolder(Class clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Class getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }
}
```

I have a test that creates a Hamcrest matcher to match the result of calling `getClazz()`:

```
public class LambdaJTest {
    @Test
    public void testClassHolder() {
        final ClassHolder classHolder = new ClassHolder(String.class);
        assertThat(classHolder, having(on(ClassHolder.class).getClazz(), is(String.class)));
    }
}
```

However, this matcher throws an exception when executed:

```
ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ArgumentConversionException: It is not possible to create a placeholder for class: java.lang.Class
    at ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ArgumentsFactory.createArgumentPlaceholder(ArgumentsFactory.java:170)
    at ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ArgumentsFactory.createArgumentPlaceholder(ArgumentsFactory.java:156)
    at ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ArgumentsFactory.createPlaceholder(ArgumentsFactory.java:52)
    at ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ArgumentsFactory.registerNewArgument(ArgumentsFactory.java:45)
    at ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ArgumentsFactory.createArgument(ArgumentsFactory.java:39)
    at ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ProxyArgument.invoke(ProxyArgument.java:36)
    at ch.lambdaj.proxy.InvocationInterceptor.intercept(InvocationInterceptor.java:42)
```

Is there a way to write such a matcher using LambdaJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need lambdaj to achieve that. It's possible to do it by using the [instanceOf matcher](http://www.jmock.org/javadoc/2.0.0/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#instanceOf%28java.lang.Class%29) as it follows:

assertThat(classHolder.getClazz(), Matchers.instanceOf(String.class)));

Comment: You're right- I don't need LambdaJ; however my question specifically asked how to do it with LambdaJ. Suppose `ClassHolder` contained another field, and I wanted to write a matcher to match on the return value of `getClazz` and this new field. LambdaJ provides a neat syntax for writing such matchers, but it doesn't work for methods that return `Class` objects.

Comment: This appears to be a limitation of LambdaJ, so I've accepted this answer on the basis of being a sensible workaround.